# Camera is not working ,properly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

In my app  i want to enable an option to take photo on a button click.i have tried this code,there is no errors but the camera IS NOT WORKING.I could not understand to solve this issue .In my xml i am using an imageview inside a frame Layout.Can anybody help me to solve the issue.

ImagePickActivity.java

```
public class ImagePickActivity extends Activity {
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_pick);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
}

public void onClick(View View) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    InputStream stream = null;
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        try {
            // recyle unused bitmaps
            if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally ch (IOException e) {
        e{
            if (stream != null)
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}}
```

XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".ImagePickActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/result"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"/>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jbn.user.imagepick" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ImagePickActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

  </manifest>
```

Comment: I cannot see anything related to _using camera_ in your code. Check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) to know how to implement camera api.

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code: 
Your Activity class

```
public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1988; 
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
} 
}
```

Your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"       
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/photo"></Button>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content">  
</ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

add to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
```

Comment: This code is actually accessing the device camera ,by passing  an intent .What i need is to develop my own camera.I want to set a view finder in to an ImageView and i need to enable an option to  take a picture when i clik the button.